# Counting possible passwords

Tags: combinatorics

Stephanie changes her password using letters and numbers to create a $6$ character code. There is no restriction on the number of times these can be used, how many combinations are possible?

The correct answer is $36^9$ but I thought it would be $36\times 35 \times 34 \times... \times 31$ because there are $36$ possible choices that occur at each $6$ slots ($36$ from number of letters + numbers ($10$ including $0$)

Comment: Your formula would be correct if you couldn't repeat an entry.

Comment: The correct answer is $36^6$.

Comment: I would have thought that letters and numbers would give a range `A..Za..z0..9`.

Comment: @scienceislife regarding the question you just deleted, it would require good knowledge of Algebra, Trig, Calculus I, part of Calculus II, together with some combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 36 different ways to put a character in the first slot, and for all of the 36 ways there are 36 different ways to put a character in the second slot, so the number of ways to put the first two characters of the password is $(36\times36)$, in the same way there are $(36\times36\times36)$ different ways to put the first three characters of the password... and there are $(36\times36\times36\times36\times36\times36)=36^6$ different ways to put all six characters of the password.

The answer would be $(36\times35\times34\times...\times31)$ if repetition of a character was not allowed in the password, then there would be 36 possibilities for the first slot, and for all those possibilities there would be only 35 possibilities left for the second slot because one of the 36 characters is used in the first slot, and there would be 34 possibilities left for the third slot because 2 of the 36 characters are used in the first and second slots, and so on.